# Please help with very simple android widget button click. Getting very frustrated. :(

Tags: android, android-widget

I have poured over every example that I can find and I have gone through the official documentation from google.  All I am trying to do is create a toast notification from a button click on a widget.

I can get the widget (and button) to appear but I can't get my intent to fire.  I have seen several examples that show doing this different ways but I just can't get it to work.  I haven't felt this helpless with coding in a long time and I'm starting to feel dumb.

This is what I have so far:

```
public class simpleclick extends AppWidgetProvider {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

        Toast.makeText(context, "doing on update", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {

            int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, simpleclick.class);
            intent.setAction("ham");
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.Timm, pendingIntent);

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);

        }

    }

    //@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     Toast.makeText(context, "action is: " + intent.getAction(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

     super.onReceive(context, intent);

    }

}
```

My manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.tblabs.simpleclick"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <receiver android:name="simpleclick">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" 
            android:resource="@xml/simpleclick" />
        </receiver>

    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="5" />

</manifest>
```

I would appreciate some help!

Thanks,
Wendy

Comment: For logging/debugging purposes it might be better to use a Log message, they output to LogCat. Anyway, you create your pending intent with getActivity(), while docs say that AppWidgetProvider is a broadcast receiver. I would try using getBroadcast() then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As **bigstones** wrote, you need to use broadcast.
Sample code:

```
protected PendingIntent getPendingSelfIntent(Context context, String action) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, getClass());
    intent.setAction(action);
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
}

views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.Timm, getPendingSelfIntent(context,
                              "ham"));
```

Answer (score 1):

here is full version:

```
package com.automatic.widget;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

public class Widget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    private static final String SYNC_CLICKED    = "automaticWidgetSyncButtonClick";

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        RemoteViews remoteViews;
        ComponentName watchWidget;

        remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
        watchWidget = new ComponentName(context, Widget.class);

        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.sync_button, getPendingSelfIntent(context, SYNC_CLICKED));
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(watchWidget, remoteViews);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onReceive(context, intent);

        if (SYNC_CLICKED.equals(intent.getAction())) {

            AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);

            RemoteViews remoteViews;
            ComponentName watchWidget;

            remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
            watchWidget = new ComponentName(context, Widget.class);

            remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.sync_button, "TESTING");

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(watchWidget, remoteViews);

        }
    }

    protected PendingIntent getPendingSelfIntent(Context context, String action) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, getClass());
        intent.setAction(action);
        return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you called `super.onReceive` at first?