# Android ImageView onClick event in Widget

Tags: android, android-widget

How can I know or catch ImageView onclicklistener?

```
public class AppWidget extends AppWidgetProvider{
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
            int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ShowActivity.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageView1, pendingIntent);
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
        }
    }
}
```

Above coding, when click on ImageView, intent to ShowActivity.class. But what I really want  is when click on ImageView, I want to display "Toast" message without going to any activity.

Comment: got answers here.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12511940/how-to-present-a-toast-when-a-widget-is-clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it will shows what do u want excatly:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ShowActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);          
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
PendingIntent pendIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.widget_layout);
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.image1, pendIntent);
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views );
```

Comment: I'm confused "where toast msg will display above coding?"

Comment: sorry!! Refer this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963865/please-help-with-very-simple-android-widget-button-click-getting-very-frustrate

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried onClickListener?

```
 ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_id);
 img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
    Toast.makeText(YourActivityName.this,
            "My Toast Text", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
 });
```

Comment: What you wrote is not for AppWidgetProvider. I mean, how to catch onclicklistener in AppWidgetProvider.

Comment: Ok I see, the question was not 100% clear - "How can I know or catch ImageView onclicklistener?"